# Row value to column, with JOIN,WHERE,SUM, similar values to different column name

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, concatenation, transpose

I have 2 tables : rc_course and rc_resultat.

rc_resultat :

[image: Table rc_resultat]

rc_course :

[image: Table rc_course]

Tables should be joined on `rc_resultat.course_id=rc_course.id`
Here is the SQL query result I'm looking for with `WHERE championnat_id=1`

[image: Result needed]

**Explanation** :

`rc_resultat.id` is the user ID, must be unique (not 2 rows with the same)

`R1,R2,...etc` are 1 colum per course_id (the column name could be the course_id, no matter, but if a user doesn't have a value for this column it should be handled). Important : as you can see, one course_id can have many points so it should be the SUM of these values.

`TOTAL` is the total amount of the row.

*To understand better, it's a championship points calculation based on multiple events where users participated or not.*

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: Yes of course, this give me all I need excepted the R1,R2,etc columns :
`("SELECT R.id,R.id,R.number, SUM(points) AS total FROM rc_resultat  AS R 
 JOIN rc_course  AS C ON C.id = R.course_id 
 WHERE championnat_id = '".$champ_id."' 
 GROUP BY R.id ORDER BY total DESC")`

I'm stuck with the transposition with Sum inside